# MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot not resolving Microservice Swagger Link

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, ocelot

I am using Ocelot in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 Project to serve as API Gateway and I have two microservices hosted.

I am trying to load Swagger documentation of both microservices from Gateway URL, however when I try to load documentation from gateway, MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot tries to load documentation from base path ie:

> https://example.com/swagger/docs/v1/token

But actual documentation path is:

> https://example.com/token/swagger/docs/v1

I have added virtual directory settings in Ocelot.Json file as well:

> "SwaggerKey": "mfa",
> "VirtualDirectory": "/authservice",

and here is my swaggerendpoint config in Ocelot.Json file:

> ```
> "SwaggerEndPoints": [
> {
>   "key": "mfa",
>   "TakeServersFromDownstreamService": true,
>   "Config": [
>     {
>       "Name": "MFA API",
>       "Version": "v1",
>       "Url": "example.com/authservice/swagger/docs/v1"
>     }
>   ]
> },
> {
>   "key": "token",
>   "Config": [
>     {
>       "Name": "Token API",
>       "Version": "v1",
>       "Url": "example.com/tservice/swagger/docs/v1"
>     }
>   ]
> }   ]
> ```

can anyone help me what am i missing in this configuration?

Comment: Hi,At first glance it looks like `https://example.com/swagger/docs/v1/token` is good address. SwagerUI send this request to Ocelot. MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot middleware, catch this request and send request for obtaining downstream documentation to `https://example.com/token/swagger/docs/v1`. So the problem is probably somewhere else. Please can you better describe your behavior and attach configuration from `startup.cs`? Thanks